# How to let a method accept two types of data as argument?

Tags: c#, .net, arguments

this is somewhat the same question as I've asked some time ago:
[How to let a method accept two types of data as argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10128823/how-to-let-a-method-accept-two-types-of-data-as-argument)

Yet the current situation differs.. a lot.

Take this:

```
public FormResourceSelector(Dictionary<string, Effect> resourceList, string type)
```

Alright, nothing wrong with it.
Now I try to run this:

```
FormResourceSelector frs = new FormResourceSelector(AreaEffect.EFFECTS, "Area effect");
FormResourceSelector frs2 = new FormResourceSelector(DistanceEffect.EFFECTS, "Distance effect");
```

Both AreaEffect and DistanceEffect (custom classes) derive from Effect.

```
public class AreaEffect : Effect
{
    public static Dictionary<string, AreaEffect> EFFECTS = new Dictionary<string, AreaEffect>();
    ...
}
```

For some reason I get the following error while making the new FormResourceSelector instance:

```
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,SCreator.AreaEffect>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,SCreator.Effect>'
```

at:

```
new FormResourceSelector(AreaEffect.EFFECTS, "Area effect");
```

I suspect the dictonary being a harass, but I don't really know how to fix this.

EDIT: Easiest would be to allow input of both Dictionary and Dictionary as resourceList in the first code snippet I've given.

Comment: Have you tried casting the input as (Effect)AreaEffect.EFFECTS ?

Comment: I need the "special" data stored in AreaEffect as well, not just the plain Effect data. It's hard to explain I'm afraid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not make your class generic?

```
public class FormResourceSelector<T>
    where T : Effect
{
    public FormResourceSelector(Dictionary<string, T> resourceList, string type)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what a "generic method" is. I've tried copy-pasting your code to begin with, but everything turns "errorish" in msvc: http://i.imgur.com/5KW8E.png .

Comment: @SwDevMan81 Ah yes, I copy-pasted on from the question

Comment: Hehe, edited now ;). No errors after a few changes. Seems like it works! Thanks a lot, I'll investigate how those generic classes really work now.

Comment: @Tgys yeah sorry, I didn't realize it was a class constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Too large for a comment, so here is llia's answer updated to compile:

```
public class FormResourceSelector<T> where T : Effect
{
    // Constructor
    public FormResourceSelector(
       Dictionary<string, T> resourceList, string type) 
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the class declaration line. Was confused about it. :)

Comment: yep... I need to pay more attention :)

Comment: No problem, we got it squared away :)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
public FormResourceSelector(Dictionary<string, Effect> resourceList, string type)
{
    resourceList.Add(new Effect());
}
```

Were you to pass a dictionary of derived types in:

```
var effects = new Dictionary<string, AreaEffect>();
new FormResourceSelector(effects, "");
```

You would have issues trying to set an `Effect` into what is *really* an `AreaEffect`, the compiler is stopping this from happening.

You could use generics in order to specify the type at compile time, as the other answer states.

Answer (score 0):

The concept at play here is know as variance - and you've run into the issue that Dictionary doesn't support covariance, as it's not read-only - this would be unsafe, for example:

```
IDictionary<string, object> myDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
myDict["hello"] = 5; // not an string
```

See: [IDictionary<TKey, TValue> in .NET 4 not covariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149589/idictionarytkey-tvalue-in-net-4-not-covariant)